# Port MySQL query to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, null, coalesce

I'm migrating my MySQL databases to PostgreSQL. While connecting database to my Python script I'm getting some syntax error. So could you please convert this MySQL query into PostgreSQL:

```
select ifnull((select ifnull(run_id,0) from searchbank order by run_id desc limit 0,1),0)
```

Comment: replace ifnull(a,b) by COALESCE(a,b)

Comment: LIMIT takes only one argument. use `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres doesn't support ifnull:

```
select coalesce((select coalesce(run_id,0)
                 from searchbank
                 order by run_id desc limit 0,1),0
               )
```

You might find this version slightly cleaner and clearer:

```
select coalesce(max(run_id), 0)
from searchbank
```

Comment: Phrase this as another question and try to format the query so it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT max(run_id) FROM searchbank), 0);
```

The only point of a query like this is to return `0` instead of **no row** if `searchbank` has no rows.

Removing the outer `SELECT` - like @Gordon demonstrates - cancels that effect and is strictly wrong.